# ruby facets map is to every as find is to?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, facet

[the every method is defined as](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/enumerable/every.rb)

```
...
def every
  per(:map)
end
...
```

does facets define a method for

```
...
    # name not relevant
def find_where
  per(:find) # or :detect
end
...
```

I've checked the [documentation](http://rubyworks.github.io/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.io/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json), most likely I'm just missing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it sort of is in their docs
[Using fluid notation](http://rubyworks.github.io/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.io/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-module-Enumerable/api-method-Enumerable-h-per)

`([1,2,3].per.map + 3)`
or in my case
`([1,2,3].per.find == 3)`